# How this oracle arithmetic operator execute

Tags: oracle, math

I need to know how the below sql query get execute

**select last_name, salary, salary+300 bonus from employees**

It gives below output

Name Salary Salary-100*12

King 24000  22800

According to me it should give first preference to Divison and multiplication. Please explain

Comment: What is your problem? Salary is 24000 so Salary-100*12=Salary-1200=22800. So it first execute multiplication then subtract.

Comment: [Operator prcedence is explained in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/operators001.htm#SQLRF51153). Why have you shown your query as +300, but the result of a different calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does "give first preference to divison and multiplication". The documentation [covers operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/operators001.htm#SQLRF51153):

> [Table 4-1](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/operators001.htm#BCFJDBDD) lists the levels of precedence among SQL operators from high to low. Operators listed on the same line have the same precedence.
>
> **Table 4-1 SQL Operator Precedence**
>
> ```
> Operator                                           Operation  
> +, - (as unary operators), PRIOR, CONNECT_BY_ROOT  Identity, negation, location in hierarchy  
> *, /                                               Multiplication, division  
> +, - (as binary operators), ||                     Addition, subtraction, concatenation
> ```

So a calculation of:

```
salary-100*12
```

is evaluated by applying the multiplication before the subtraction; or more explicitly:

```
salary-(100*12)
```

which is just

```
salary-1200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex Poole